# SQL Server is the table locked?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2000 (With SQL 8.02). Is there a query which will say if the table if locked?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
db_name(resource_database_id) AS DBName,
object_name(resource_associated_entity_id, resource_database_id) AS Object,
request_session_id AS SPID,  request_mode AS RMode, request_type AS RType,
request_status AS RStatus
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_type = 'object'
```

Comment: And for SQL Server 2000, like it say in the question?

Comment: No, sorry - it is my mistake. For 2000 - http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;271509